# How should I set up an Indeterminate Progress in a custom Action Bar layout?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've created a custom layout for my app's Action Bar. Everything's working fine except that the Indeterminate Progress that I enable in `onCreate()` via `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` shows up to the right of my custom layout and moves everything over whenever it appears:

[image]

Here's my custom Action Bar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:queryHint="@string/menu_search_hint"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/search_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can I do to the `ProgressBar` in my custom Action Bar layout so that `requestWindowFeature()` finds and uses it instead of the default one?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution. Instead of using `requestWindowFeature()`, I referenced the ProgressBar I'd placed in the ActionBar layout and replaced all instances of `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()` with `setVisibility()`:

```
// Toggles progress spinner visibility when we conduct a search 
private void toggleIndeterminateSpinner(int state)
{
    // Indeterminate Progress Spinner
    ProgressBar progressSpinner = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);

    switch(state)
    {
    case HIDE:
        progressSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case SHOW:
        progressSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
}
```